# Creating an object containing functions using jquery extend

Tags: jquery, global, extend, utility

I have three js files in my project and there are around 15 functions repeated in each file.
They are sort of utility functions.
To avoid this repetition, I used $.extend :

```
$.extend({
   myFunction1 : function(){},
   myFunction2 : funciton(){},...and so on
});
```

This approach worked perfectly and I was able to call $.myFunction1() anywhere in the js file.

But, I wanted to create an object that contains all these utility functions. So my other approach was like

```
MyApp = {
  myFunction1 : function(){},
   myFunction2 : funciton(){}, ... and so on
}
```

And I was able to call MyApp.myFunction1() anywhere in the 3 files as **MyApp** is a global variable.

But I do not want to make it a global variable. All I want is I could call **$.MyApp.myFunction1()** anywhere in my code. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see the only sensible option is a global object. If you want to access something from **anywhere** it needs to be global.

If you look at most utility libraries e.g http://underscorejs.org/ you will see the same thing. They use a global namespace (similar to your MyApp object) which is just named '_'.

If you try to add the functions to each object individually you will be duplicating them in memory for each object which is a waste.